# Reverse Calculate Ellipsoidal Height

Tags: geodesy

I have a few hundred points with ellipsoidal height taken a few years ago. Based on these ellipsoidal heights I had deduced orthometric heights for the same.

Is there a way to find the ellipsoidal height of another point relative to these hundred points on that same ellipsoid? Maybe reconstruct the ellipsoid geometry keeping these hundred as fixed.

Comment: Search with keywords `spatial interpolation`, also `kriging interpolation`, and learn.